# BeEquivalentTo doesn't work with Anonymous Methods

Tags: fluent-assertions

I have an xunit test using FA 4.19.3.  I have recently upgraded to 5.3.0 without too many issues, except for some Object graph comparisons.

Old test:

```cs
var result = await MyClass.GetResultAsync();

result.ShouldBeEquivalentTo(new
{
    StatusCode = 200,
    Exception = (Exception)null        
}, options => options.Excluding(o => o.Context));
```

But because the expectation is an anonymous method the Excluding errors with:

> 'IMemberInfo' does not contain a definition for 'Context' and no
>   extension method 'Context' accepting a first argument of type
>   'IMemberInfo' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an
>   assembly reference?)

I even tried defining the generic:

```
result.Should().BeEquivalentTo<MyResult>(
```

but this did not help.

How can I continue to use the anon method as I have many tests using this method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually, we introduced some pretty big breaking changes in 5.0 just to make it possible to compare against an anonymous type. The `Excluding` method is there to exclude properties from the *expectation*. Since your expectation doesn't have an `Context` object, FA will complain about that. Check out https://www.continuousimprover.com/2018/02/fluent-assertions-50-best-unit-test.html#redefining-equivalency

Comment: Thank you, worked fine removing the options completely.  And thanks for the article.